# Jenkins Error: fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'xyz.h': No such file or directory

Tags: testing, jenkins, static

Can any one please tell me how to resolve this kind of error?

This header file placed in different folder and project.sln file present in some other folder. but both folders are present at same master folder like :

Project_Data(main folder)
1. Source_code (project.sln present here)
2. Supported_Files(xyz.h file present here)
and in jenkins i give the svn location of master folder.

Comment: What is "this kind of error"? The one from the title? How does it get triggered?

Comment: Hello Nico Haase,                                                                                                    I am getting this error in jenkins. The meaning of this error is while building my project some header file is not able to find by jenkins. But in my question i mentioned full scenario.

Comment: So, is this a problem of jenkins itself or of building a project? The second one is not covered in your question

Comment: This build problem related to jenkins. Because jenkins always pick only Source_code (project.sln present here) folder not other supported file folder.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly thank you for your response to my question. Now i got the solution of above error.

- In this case we can change the location of missing file(i.e which is not found by jenkins while exection) to folder where .sln file placed.We can do this process manually or we can write execution script to automate this process.

Thanks :)